# VBA Type mismatch, Run-time error 13

Tags: vba, types, range, mismatch

I just wrote a small VBA function that looks as below. As function output, I would like to get the Range

```
Public Function selectRows(col As String) As Range

Dim begin, fini As Integer
Set TopCell = Cells(1, col)
Set BottomCell = Cells(Rows.Count, col)
If IsEmpty(TopCell) Then Set TopCell = TopCell.End(xlDown)
If IsEmpty(BottomCell) Then Set BottomCell = BottomCell.End(xlUp)
begin = TopCell.Row
fini = BottomCell.Row
Set selectRows = Activesheet.Range(col & begin & ":" & col & fini)
End Function
```

Then I get a Type mismatch error when it tries to set output =Range(...)

Could you please help me to fix this issue, thx a lot in advance

Comment: Functions return values. But you don't set `selectRows` to anything in this function.

Answer (score 2):

It is a very bad idea to use a reserved word such as column as the name of your variable. If you want the function to return a range, you want:

```
Set selectRows = Range(scol & TopCell.Row & ":" & scol & BottomCell.Row)
```

Rather than:

```
Set output = Range(column & TopCell.Row & ":" & column & BottomCell.Row)
```

There are other problems, such as if the column is empty.

Comment: Hi Remou, unfortunately I still get the error? The column is not empty, I have values in the column

Comment: @Eva I don't, once I replace all reference to Column. Add a breakpoint (F9) and check the value of topcell and bottomcell.

Comment: Yes I have the values for topcell and bottomcell, but the following command causes the type mismatch error: Set selectRows = Range(....)

Comment: @Eva What happens if you prefix range with a worksheet? Sheet1.range, or Activesheet.Range?

Comment: I edited the code above according your suggestions, as you can see, but still, the assignment of the range to outp does not work, i don't get it;-)

Comment: Open a new workbook, fill a few values into a column, paste in your function and run it. BTW, the function will still not have a return value, but leave that for now.

Comment: You may find it easier in your last line to use the construct ActiveSheet.Range(cells(col,begin),cells(col,fini))

Comment: Minor side note, begin is not typed.  You need to use Dim begin as Integer, fini As Integer  in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You're putting in an input that is greater than the number of columns that you have. For example, my Excel 2003 has `IV` columns, when I put in `IW` it throws the `Error 13`. I'll leave my code below if you want to clean your code up. Some error handling would help so this wouldn't happen again.

```
Public Function selectRows(ByVal sColumn As String) As Range

    Dim lColumn As Long
    Dim TopCell As Range, BottomCell As Range
    Dim wks As Worksheet

    Set wks = ActiveSheet

    lColumn = wks.Range(sColumn & "1").Column

    Set TopCell = wks.Cells(1, lColumn)
    Set BottomCell = wks.Cells(Rows.Count, lColumn)
    If IsEmpty(TopCell) Then Set TopCell = TopCell.End(xlDown)
    If IsEmpty(BottomCell) Then Set BottomCell = BottomCell.End(xlUp)
    Set selectRows = wks.Range(TopCell, BottomCell)

End Function
```